# Django, deleting an object and creating new one at the same moment (in new model)

Tags: django

I am looking for a way how to delete an object and create new one (in new model) at the same time. I mean I want to have a base of deleted elements. I got table with delete button within form (DeleteView). Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override **delete** method

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods

or use singnals, but I would recommend first option.